# jQuery hover fadein and change class

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm working on a "latest projects" page .. the projects appear as linked photos inside an li tag.. i want to add jquery in which when some one hover the photo it fadesIn changing the background color and viewing a small pic in the middle ... the li code is ..

```
<li><a class="workslinks" href="#"><img src="img/home/l_work/1.png" alt="1" /><div style="z-index:1;" class="workhover"><div class="hoversymbol"></div></div></a></li>
```

CSS :

```
li{
    float:right;
    list-style:none;
}
li a{
    display: block;
    width: 215px;
    height: 115px;
    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
    padding: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px #eee solid;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #f1f1f1;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #f1f1f1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 8px #f1f1f1;
}
li a img{
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
li a img:hover{
    background: #000;
    opacity:1.0;
}
li a .workhover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
    width: 215px;
    height: 115px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    display: none;
}

li a .workhover .hoversymbol {
    background:url(../img/home/l_work/links.png) center center no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

for the jquery code i tried a code to remove a class with `hidden` property assotiated with `workhover` div when hovering but it dids for all the list elements not the selected ones only :(

=================

just i want a code that when hovering `.workslinks` it changes the value of opacity of `.workhover` from 0 to 1 slowly .. so that it appears like fade in ,, mmm is that possible? with no CSS transitions

Comment: Show us the code you tried.

Comment: just i want a code that when hovering `.workslinks` it changes the value of opacity of `.workhover` from 0 to 1 slowly .. so that it appears like fade in ,, mmm is that possible?
with no CSS transitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fadeIn()` abnd `fadeOut() methods in jQuery because the`.workhover`object is initially`display: none`:

```
$(".workslinks").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".workhover").stop(true).fadeIn(1000, 1);
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".workhover").stop(true).fadeOut(1000, 0);
});
```

Comment: all i want is a code that when hovering `.workslinks` it changes the value of opacity of `.workhover` from 0 to 1 slowly .. so that it appears like fade in ,, mmm is that possible? with no CSS transitions...

your code fade the `.workslinks` it self .. @>@

Comment: @user2217482 - I've modified my answer to change the opacity of the `.workhover` object that is inside the `.workslinks` that is being hovered with the mouse.  It is not clear at all in your question what you want.  I would suggest you use the edit button in your question to spell out the exact behavior you want.

Comment: Thxxx .. but how can i originally make `.workhover` invisible .. this is why i reqwested a code changing the opacity ... the opacity will be set to 0 as default and then i want a code which changes the opacity of `.workhover` from 0 to 1 with slow speed when some one hover `.workslinks`

Comment: @user2217482 - without a working example, it's hard to see all the interaction of the code and CSS.  I changed my answer to work with a part of your CSS that I didn't initially follow.  If you need further help, please make a working jsFiddle out of the code so I can see the same thing you see and make sure everything works.

Comment: @user2217482 - I tried to make a simplified jsFiddle that illustrates my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Pxbn6/